# When I create a new user, how do I automatically create a .virtualenvs directory in their home directory?

Tags: users, adduser

I want to automatically create a directory called ".virtualenvs" in each new user's home directory upon creation of that new user.

I am using the useradd command to create new users.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create the directory `/etc/skel/.virtualenvs`. The `/etc/skel` directory will be used as a skeleton for a new home directory.

It's defined in `/etc/adduser.conf`:

```
# The SKEL variable specifies the directory containing "skeletal" user
# files; in other words, files such as a sample .profile that will be
# copied to the new user's home directory when it is created.
SKEL=/etc/skel
```

Comment: If you're giving your users virtualenvwrapper you can add the `$WORKON_HOME` environment variable to `/etc/skel/.bashrc` as well