# How to set default PATH variable

Tags: 13.04

I broke the `/home/username/.profile` file so now I can't access Ubuntu. How can I reset the .profile file back to its defaults? When I try to write something using root, I get error message that the file is read only. I broke PATH variable to be more accurate.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `PATH` variable is defined in `/etc/environment`. To reset the path variable, open a terminal and execute the following command: `. /etc/environment`.

That will restore the `PATH` variable for the current terminal only!

To restore the `.profile` file copy it from the folder `/etc/skel`. The `/etc/skel` folder contains all the files that are copied to the user's home folder when a new user is created.

Also take a look at that answer: [When I create a new user, how do I automatically create a .virtualenvs directory in their home directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29111/when-i-create-a-new-user-how-do-i-automatically-create-a-virtualenvs-directory)

If you are unable to log-in the you have to use a live-cd and then copy the content of the skeleton folder (`/etc/skel`) into your home directory.

**Update:**

To access your home or partition using a live-cd you have to mount your harddisk after you bootet up from the live-cd. Open a terminal in the live-cd and type the following:

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/root
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/root
```

Now your hard drive is mounted into the folder `/mnt/root`. Now copy the content of the skeleton folder into your home folder

```
cp -r /mnt/root/etc/skel/ /mnt/root/home/<your-user-name>/
```

The `-r` switch is important to copy the hidden files. Now you can unmount the disk and reboot the system `cd && sync && umount /dev/sda1 && reboot` (as root)

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I restored PATH variable as you said, but I can't restore .profile since my file system is read-only. Can you show me how to make it writeable so I can change .profile. EDIT: I don't know how to access home folder from live cd, I only see Ubuntu home folder, there is no my home folder which I use.

Comment: Use the following command: `sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda1 /`. That assumes that your primary partiton is `sda1`. Just use the `mount` command to check.

Comment: You are welcome, just added some stuff how to fix it using a live-cd.