# How to create Maildir on user creation?

Tags: adduser, maildir

How do I make the `adduser` script create the appropriate `Maildir` directory of the new user?

---

I have an Ubuntu server running postfix. When I first installed it was deliverying emails to `/var/mail/<user>/`.

I've changed to use `/home/<user>/Maildir` by putting `home_mailbox = Maildir/` on `/etc/postfix/main.cf`.

At first I didn't worked because there wasn't a `Maildir` directory for my user (email was *delivered back* on my provider with the error).

Then I created the `Maildir` directory, with the subdirectories `new`, `cur` and `tmp` as Maildir uses. Worked fine after that.

But this way I would have to manually create those directories everytime I add an user. Is there anyway to make the `adduser` script (that is what I use) to create those for me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When I create a new user, how do I automatically create a .virtualenvs directory in their home directory?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/29111/when-i-create-a-new-user-how-do-i-automatically-create-a-virtualenvs-directory)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this manpage](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/adduser8.html) on `adduser`, it will copy anything present in `/etc/skel` (or another skeleton directory, if specified) to the newly created home directory. The [Ubuntu manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/adduser.8.html) only mentions files, but I think the functionality might hold for directories as well. So I suggest that you create a `Maildir` directory in `/etc/skel`, along with `cur`, `new` and `tmp` subdirectories. According to the answer to [When I create a new user, how do I automatically create a .virtualenvs directory in their home directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29111/when-i-create-a-new-user-how-do-i-automatically-create-a-virtualenvs-directory), it works for directories as well.

Comment: Great, looks like just what I needed. I'm going to test it later; after that I come here and comment if it worked.